# How to change the jQuery ID selector with a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

In my html file I have #book1 #book2 etc. as divs.

I'm trying to set it up so that I can call the function (addToPage) for each product and pass in my object (book1) and it will put my product info onto the page. Any help is appreciated!

```
var book1 = {
name:'name of book', 
author:'name of author'
}

//////////// THIS WORKS

function addToPage(productId) {
$('#book1 .name').text(productId.name);
$('#book1 .author').text(productId.author);
}
addToPage(book1)

/////////// THIS DOESN'T WORK / CAN YOU TELL ME WHY?

function addToPage(productId) {
$('#productId .name').text(productId.name);
$('#productId .author').text(productId.author);
}
addToPage(book1)
```

Comment: `#book1` will work when you have an html element with id `book1`.  perhaps `#productId` is not working because there is no html element with id `productId`

Comment: Do you have element productId on page?

Comment: You're right I have an element with id book1. I would like productId to change to book1 when I pass book1 through my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in an object. So the variable will not be available as part of the argument.

Use

```js
var book1 = {
  id: 'book1',
  name: 'name of book',
  author: 'name of author'
}

function addToPage(product) {
  $('#' + product.id + ' .name').text(product.name);
  $('#' + product.id + ' .author').text(product.author);
}

addToPage(book1)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="book1">
  <p class="name"></p>
  <p class="author"></p>
</div>
```

I believe you have the elements `book1` and `book2` etc in you HTML. But you jQuery selector is looking for an element by id `productId` . You need to replace that with the variable that you are passing in so that you are making the right selection.

Comment: @SebastianNette. Thanks,, Fixed it !